# select minimum date after maximum gap oracle

Tags: oracle

I have data for a member like below

```
EFF_DT-Term_dt
1/1/13-7/31/14
1/1/15-3/31/15
5/1/15-5/31/15
6/1/15-12/31/15
1/1/16-12/31/16
```

Here there are 2 gaps - after 7/31/14 and 3/31/15. I want to select the row 5/1/15-5/31/15 as it is the minimum date after maximum gap. I tried using

```
select ( FIRST_VALUE(EFF_DT) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY FLAG DESC) AS CUR_EFF_DT)
from
(
select   EFF_DT,     
CASE WHEN LAG(TERM_DT, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY MemberID ORDER BY TERM_DT) = EFF_DT - 1 THEN 0
           ELSE sequence.nextval
END AS FLAG
from effective_dates_table).
```

This is giving correct result, but i don't want to use sequence Is there any other easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way... compute the differences using the analytic `LAG()` function, then group by `member_id` and use the aggregate `LAST()` function.

NOTE: there may be more than one pair of rows with the same, greatest gap between `term_dt` and the following `eff_dt`. You must clarify which row should be selected if that happens. The solution below picks the earliest occurrence (if this happens). If you want the latest occurrence, change `MIN` to `MAX`. If you want something else, just say what the requirement is.

```
with
     inputs ( member_id, eff_dt, term_dt ) as (
       select 101, to_date('1/1/13', 'mm/dd/yy'), to_date('7/31/14' , 'mm/dd/yy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('1/1/15', 'mm/dd/yy'), to_date('3/31/15' , 'mm/dd/yy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('5/1/15', 'mm/dd/yy'), to_date('5/31/15' , 'mm/dd/yy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('6/1/15', 'mm/dd/yy'), to_date('12/31/15', 'mm/dd/yy') from dual union all
       select 101, to_date('1/1/16', 'mm/dd/yy'), to_date('12/31/16', 'mm/dd/yy') from dual
     )
-- End of simulated inputs (for testing only, not part of the solution).
-- Use your actual table and column names in the SQL query below.
select member_id,
       min(eff_dt)  keep (dense_rank last order by diff nulls first) as eff_dt,
       min(term_dt) keep (dense_rank last order by diff nulls first) as term_dt
from   (
         select member_id, eff_dt, term_dt,
                eff_dt - lag(term_dt) over (partition by member_id order by eff_dt) as diff
         from   inputs
       )
group by member_id
;

MEMBER_ID  EFF_DT               TERM_DT           
---------  -------------------  -------------------
      101  2015-01-01 00:00:00  2015-03-31 00:00:00
```